# in-app-purchase - check for purchased items before initializing the app

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I have following problem:

My app is downloadable for free but can be upgraded through in-app-purchase.
The purchase is working fine. Now I'm checking at startup if the app is upgraded or not in order to initialize the free or the upgraded features.

At default the app assumes that it is NOT upgraded, using a bool which is set to 'false' as default. At startup the app queries the purchased items and sets the bool to true if the upgraded version was purchased.

The problem is that a connection to google play with a service is done asynchronously. That means that at startup is some cases the app is considered as not upgraded although it is, because of the asynchronous service connections which takes too long.

Is it possible to wait for the service connection to finish before checking for the app version?
The docs say that with API-Version 3 the purchase informations are cached locally. Isn't it possible to retrieve the cached informations without using an asynchronous service connection?

Of course I could save the upgrade-informations by myself using preferences but if the user
likes to install the app on another device an upgraded version would be treated as not upgraded.
Did anybody faced the same problem and found a way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look [here](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html#caching):

It says "Version 3 API calls will be serviced through cache lookups instead of through a network connection to Google Play".

Meaning, Google Play Service optimizes your requests to return cached results (if any available), although this happens asynchronously because of Inter Process Communication between your app and Google Play Services.

I would suggest when your app is installed on a new device. Start as if the free version is loaded while checking previous purchases in the "background" and gracefully upgrade if the user already owns an upgrade.

Comment: Thanks for the information but this does not solve my problem. It is still asynchronous and I can not rely on the result at startup.

Comment: I just edited my post with a suggestion, see if that solves your issue. Although, I don't think there is a way to check previous purchases instantaneously.

Comment: Another way would be to make the user wait(show a progess bar or something) until you get a response from G-Play services.

Comment: Your edited suggestion might work. I'll start the app as a free version and if the service detects the upgraded version I can show a message like 'upgraded version detected' or something like this, save the result in the preferences and restart the app. I think this will work but it is quite complicated and not optimal for the user. I'll try this suggestion and if I'll not receive a better answer I'll accept yours :).